# How to Redirect Unconfirmed Users Using Ruby on Rails and the Devise Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, warden

I would like to change the user sign-in behaviour of devise in a way to redirect a user to a different page when that user is not confirmed.

I have the following code in my `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`:

```
  # POST /user/sign_in
  def create

    @user = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user) 
    sign_in @user
     respond_with @user, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(@user)

  end
```

When the user has put correct username/password and is not confirmed Warden will raise an error that will redirect the user to the sign in page (code 302). At the same time this will put flash[:alert] to "unconfirmed".

Is there a way to redirect an unconfirmed user to a specific page?

My idea to work around this was reading the flash[:alert] value and redirecting to the appropriate page if the value is "unconfirmed" but warden is not sending additional data about the user.

Comment: You got this working?

Answer (score 2):

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    @user = User.where(:email => params[:user][:email])[0] # you get the user now
    if @user.confirmed?
      super
    else
      redirect_to YOUR_DESIRED_path # or something else you want to do
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: FYI... This doesn't work at this point.  If you want to do this, you need to handle it in a custom FailureApp.  Directions in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom FailureApp to do this (and you need to define /unconfirmed in your routes, etc., like any other Rails action):

lib/custom_failure.rb

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    if warden_message == :unconfirmed
      '/unconfirmed'
    else
      super
    end
  end

  # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

Comment: You are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

I think that to get this working you need to combine Brian's answer with an addition to your routes.rb file.

I'm going to test it out right now so I'll give you an update if/when I get it working. (EDIT: I've got this working locally).

Here's what you need to do:

1. Create an new file in `your_rails_app/app/controllers` called `sessions_controller.rb` which should look like this:

   ```
   class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
     def create
       @user = User.where(:email => params[:user][:email])[0] # you get the user now
       if @user.confirmed?
         super
       else
         redirect_to YOUR_DESIRED_path # or something else you want to do
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Add the following line to your routes.rb file (or modify the line in your routes.rb file that contains `devise_for :users` ...or whatever your model is called):

   ```
   devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }
   ```
3. You need to add this to your `User` model:

   ```
    protected
    def confirmation_required?
      false
    end
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Please put this line into devise.rb, if you do not want to allow unconfirmed user to sign in
after successful registration.

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil
```